# Google timeline chart add 4th piece of data a string in hover

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am working with one of their examples, in essence I need this functionality with the addition of when you hover over one of the values on the chart, I need a 4th data element.

The example here is superbowl winning football teams. When you hover over one of the time series items, I would also like to show the score of the game. (I need this chart with one more piece of addition text data in the hover.

This code is directly from googles example:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['timeline']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Asset');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Arrive');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Depart');

  data.addRows([
    ['Baltimore Ravens', new Date(2000, 8, 5), new Date(2001, 1, 5)],
    ['New England Patriots', new Date(2001, 8, 5), new Date(2002, 1, 5)],
    ['Tampa Bay Buccaneers', new Date(2002, 8, 5), new Date(2003, 1, 5)],
    ['New England Patriots', new Date(2003, 8, 5), new Date(2004, 1, 5)],
    ['New England Patriots', new Date(2004, 8, 5), new Date(2005, 1, 5)],
    ['Pittsburgh Steelers', new Date(2004, 8, 5), new Date(2005, 1, 5)],
    ['Pittsburgh Steelers', new Date(2005, 8, 5), new Date(2006, 1, 5)],
    ['Indianapolis Colts', new Date(2006, 8, 5), new Date(2007, 1, 5)],
    ['New York Giants', new Date(2007, 8, 5), new Date(2008, 1, 5)],
    ['Pittsburgh Steelers', new Date(2008, 8, 5), new Date(2009, 1, 5)],
    ['New Orleans Saints', new Date(2009, 8, 5), new Date(2010, 1, 5)],
    ['Green Bay Packers', new Date(2010, 8, 5), new Date(2011, 1, 5)],
    ['New York Giants', new Date(2011, 8, 5), new Date(2012, 1, 5)],
    ['Baltimore Ravens', new Date(2012, 8, 5), new Date(2013, 1, 5)],
    ['Seattle Seahawks', new Date(2013, 8, 5), new Date(2014, 1, 5)],
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 450,
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: true
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no standard configuration options to change the default tooltip

but you can add your own custom tooltip, see [Customizing tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#customizing-tooltips) in the Timeline reference

in order to add a custom tooltip, you must provide all 5 columns in the data table.
(row label, bar label, tooltip, start, and end)

the tooltip column will just be a string, either a simple value or html

see following working snippet,
here, a `DataView` is used to add the tooltip column.
this allows the tooltip to be built dynamically based on the data in the data table

also, the score of the game is added to the original data table, for easy reference,
but is excluded from the data view...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Asset');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Arrive');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Depart');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Score');
  data.addRows([
    ['Baltimore Ravens', new Date(2000, 8, 5), new Date(2001, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['New England Patriots', new Date(2001, 8, 5), new Date(2002, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['Tampa Bay Buccaneers', new Date(2002, 8, 5), new Date(2003, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['New England Patriots', new Date(2003, 8, 5), new Date(2004, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['New England Patriots', new Date(2004, 8, 5), new Date(2005, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['Pittsburgh Steelers', new Date(2004, 8, 5), new Date(2005, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['Pittsburgh Steelers', new Date(2005, 8, 5), new Date(2006, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['Indianapolis Colts', new Date(2006, 8, 5), new Date(2007, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['New York Giants', new Date(2007, 8, 5), new Date(2008, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['Pittsburgh Steelers', new Date(2008, 8, 5), new Date(2009, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['New Orleans Saints', new Date(2009, 8, 5), new Date(2010, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['Green Bay Packers', new Date(2010, 8, 5), new Date(2011, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['New York Giants', new Date(2011, 8, 5), new Date(2012, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['Baltimore Ravens', new Date(2012, 8, 5), new Date(2013, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
    ['Seattle Seahawks', new Date(2013, 8, 5), new Date(2014, 1, 5), '35 - 21'],
  ]);

  var formatMonth = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, {
    label: 'bar label',
    type: 'string',
    calc: function () {
      return null;
    }
  }, {
    role: 'tooltip',
    type: 'string',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      // build tooltip
      var dateBegin = dt.getValue(row, 1);
      var dateEnd = dt.getValue(row, 2);
      var oneDay = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      var duration = (((dateEnd.getTime() - dateBegin.getTime()) / oneDay) / 365.25) * 12;

      var tooltip = '<div><div class="ggl-tooltip"><span>';
      tooltip += dt.getValue(row, 0) + '</span></div>';
      tooltip += '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><div>' + formatMonth.formatValue(dateBegin) + ' - ';
      tooltip += formatMonth.formatValue(dateEnd) + '</div>';
      tooltip += '<div><span>Duration: </span>' + duration.toFixed(0) + ' months</div></div>';
      tooltip += '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><span>Score: </span>' + dt.getValue(row, 3) + '</div></div>';

      return tooltip;
    },
    p: {html: true}
  }, 1, 2]);

  var options = {
    height: 450,
    timeline: {
      groupByRowLabel: true
    },
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view.toDataTable(), options);  // <-- use data view to draw chart
});
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.ggl-tooltip div {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.ggl-tooltip span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: yep this is fantastic thank you for the information, I am trying to see how to accept this as the answer